# suppress highlight around special characters in tcolorbox and minted

Tags: tcolorbox, minted

I am using tcolorbox for listing some (bash) code. I'd like to suppress the dimmed highlighting around special characters ($, { and }) in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,skins}

\newtcblisting{bashcode}{
  listing engine=minted,
  colback=black!10,
  colframe=black!70,
  listing only,
  minted style=colorful,
  minted language=bash,
  minted options={linenos=false,texcl=false,fontsize=\footnotesize},
  left=1mm,
}

\begin{document}

Set environment variables:
\begin{bashcode}
  $ export ROOTSYS=${HOME}/root
\end{bashcode}

\end{document}
```

the result being:
[image]

Comment: I think that the background coloring of `${`...`}` is defined by the selected `colorful` Pygments style. According to http://pygments.org/docs/styles/#creating-own-styles, you could build your own style (without background coloring). I never tried this myself, but the web link says it's easy (hopefully).