# latex style to emulate appearance of a terminal window

Tags: formatting, console

I am writing on computer science and UNIX systems.  Is there a latex package or style file for creating the image of a terminal window on a page?

Comment: https://www.alanshawn.com/tech/2019/09/01/emulate-terminal.html seems promising (but I didn't test it myself)

Comment: There is also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173850/problem-in-adding-a-background-color-in-a-minted-environment and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395470/suppress-highlight-around-special-characters-in-tcolorbox-and-minted and a very nice example at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452150/advanced-customization-of-minted-code that unfortunately does not come with source code.

Comment: You might try the relatively new `termsim` package from CTAN.

Comment: Gonna give it a whirl